# Using Crank-Nicolson to solve the diffusion equation with variable diffusivity and flux boundary condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I'm trying to solve the diffusion equation with variable diffusivity and a zero-flux boundary condition at one boundary, and a flux that is proportional to concentration at the other boundary. The equation is
$$    \frac{\partial C(x,t)}{\partial t} =
    \frac{\partial }{\partial x} \left( D(x) \frac{\partial C(x,t) }{\partial x} \right)
= \left(\frac{\partial D(x)}{\partial x}\right) \left(\frac{\partial C(x,t)}{\partial x} \right) + D(x)\left(\frac{\partial^2 C(x,t)}{\partial x^2} \right),
$$
where $D(x)$ is the diffusivity. I discretise the expanded version (to the right of the equals sign above) of the equation using central second-order finite differences for both the first and second derivatives, as well as the implicit midpoint method in time, and get

$$\frac{C_n^{i+1}-C_n^i}{\Delta t} = \frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{D_{n+1}-D_{n-1}}{2\Delta x}\frac{C_{n+1}^{i+1}-C_{n-1}^{i+1}}{2\Delta x} + D_n\frac{C_{n+1}^{i+1}-2C_{n}^{i+1} + C_{n-1}^{i+1}}{\Delta x^2} \\ 
+ \frac{D_{n+1}-D_{n-1}}{2\Delta x}\frac{C_{n+1}^{i}-C_{n-1}^{i}}{2\Delta x} + D_n\frac{C_{n+1}^{i}-2C_{n}^{i} + C_{n-1}^{i}}{\Delta x^2}\right],$$

where $C_n^i = C(x_n, t_i)$ and $D_n = D(z_n)$. We can re-write this a bit, to get:

$$
  C_{n-1}^{i+1} \left[ \frac{\alpha}{4} D'_n - \alpha D_n \right]
+ C_{n  }^{i+1} \left[1  + 2 \alpha D_n \right]
+ C_{n+1}^{i+1} \left[ -\frac{\alpha}{4} D'_n - \alpha D_n \right]
\\ =
  C_{n-1}^{i} \left[ -\frac{\alpha}{4} D'_n + \alpha D_n \right]
+ C_{n  }^{i} \left[1  - 2 \alpha D_n \right]
+ C_{n+1}^{i} \left[ \frac{\alpha}{4} D'_n + \alpha D_n \right].
$$
Here, I have used $\alpha = \frac{\Delta t}{2\Delta x^2}$ and $D'_n = D_{n+1} - D_{n-1}$.

We see that this can be written as a tridiagonal system of equations, but before we can solve it the next step is to deal with the boundaries, to eliminate the points outside the boundary.

Let $x_n = x_0 + n \Delta x$ where $n=0,1,...,N-1$, for a total of $N$ points. At the boundary at $x_0$, I want a no-flux boundary condition. The diffusive flux is given by Fick's law,

$$
j_D(x_n, t) = D(x_n) \left. \frac{\partial C(x,t)}{\partial x}\right|_{x_n}.
$$

I know that for my problem, $D(x) > 0$ everywhere, and hence zero flux at $x_0$ implies $\left. \frac{\partial C(x,t)}{\partial x}\right|_{x_0} = 0$, which again implies $C_{-1}^i = C_{1}^i$ when using the same central finite difference as before. Hence I can eliminate $C_{-1}^i$ and $C_{-1}^{i+1}$ from my system of equations.

**So far, I think this is pretty standard and ok.**

Next, we get to the more interesting boundary condition, where I want the flux out across the boundary at $x_{N-1}$, at time $t_i$ to be equal to $kC_{N-1}^i$, where $k$ is some constant. Again, I use Fick's law and say that I want the diffusive flux to have this value, which yields

$$
j_D(x_{N-1}, t_i) = D_{N-1} \left. \frac{\partial C(x,t_i)}{\partial x}\right|_{x_{N-1}} = k C_{N-1}^i.
$$

I again use the central finite difference to approximate the derivative, which gives me

$$
D_{N-1} \frac{C_{N}^i - C_{N-2}^i}{2 \Delta x} = k C_{N-1}^i,
$$

and again since I know that $D_{N-1} > 0$, I can rewrite to get the following expression:

$$
C_{N}^i  = \frac{2 \Delta x \, k C_{N-1}^i}{D_{N-1}} +  C_{N-2}^i,
$$

which I can use to eliminate $C_N^i$ and $C_N^{i+1}$ from my equations.

Finally, the way I have defined $D'_n = D_{n+1} - D_{n-1}$ means that I also have to treat the boundaries separately, so I say that $D'_0 = 2(D_1 - D_0)$ and $D'_{N-1} = 2(D_{N-1} - D_{N-2})$. This is essentially the same as switching the differentiation of $D(x)$ to first-order one-sided finite differences at the boundaries (recall that $\Delta x$ doesn't appear here since I've put it into $\alpha$). I also happen to know that for my problem, I typically expect $D(x)$ to be a linear function near the boundaries, so this should be fine.

In the end, I end up with the linear equation system

$$\mathbf{L}\mathbf{C}^{i+1}=\mathbf{R}\mathbf{C}^{i},$$

where $\mathbf{C}^i = [C_0^i, C_1^i, ..., C_{N-1}^i]$, and the tridiagonal matrices $\mathbf{L}$ and $\mathbf{R}$ are shown below:

$$
\mathbf{L}=\left[
    \begin{array}{ccccccc}
        1 + 2 \alpha D_0 & - 2 \alpha D_0 & 0 & & & 0 & 0 \\
        \frac{\alpha}{4} D'_1 - \alpha D_1 & 1 + 2 \alpha D_1 & -\frac{\alpha}{4} D'_1 - \alpha D_1 & 0 & & & 0 \\
    0 &\ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 & & \\
        & 0 & \frac{\alpha}{4} D'_n - \alpha D_n & 1 + 2 \alpha D_n & -\frac{\alpha}{4} D'_n - \alpha D_n & 0 &  \\
     & & 0 &\ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
        0 & & & 0 & \frac{\alpha}{4} D'_{N-1} - \alpha D_{N-1} & 1 + 2\alpha D_{N-1} & -\frac{\alpha}{4} D'_{N-1} - \alpha D_{N-1} \\
    0 & 0 & & & 0 & -2 \alpha D_N & 1 + 2 \alpha D_N - 2 \alpha \Gamma
    \end{array}
    \right]
$$

$$
\mathbf{R}=\left[
    \begin{array}{ccccccc}
        1 - 2 \alpha D_0 &  2 \alpha D_0 & 0 & & & 0 & 0 \\
        -\frac{\alpha}{4} D'_1 + \alpha D_1 & 1 - 2 \alpha D_1 & \frac{\alpha}{4} D'_1 - \alpha D_1 & 0 & & & 0 \\
    0 &\ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 & & \\
        & 0 & -\frac{\alpha}{4} D'_n + \alpha D_n & 1 - 2 \alpha D_n & \frac{\alpha}{4} D'_n + \alpha D_n & 0 &  \\
     & & 0 &\ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
        0 & & & 0 & -\frac{\alpha}{4} D'_{N-1} + \alpha D_{N-1} & 1 - 2\alpha D_{N-1} & \frac{\alpha}{4} D'_{N-1} + \alpha D_{N-1} \\
    0 & 0 & & & 0 & 2 \alpha D_N & 1 - 2 \alpha D_N + 2 \alpha \Gamma
    \end{array}
    \right]
$$

where I have introduced the variable $\Gamma$ to make the matrices fit on the screen:
$$
\Gamma = k \, \Delta x \left(1 + \frac{1}{4}\frac{D'_{N-1}}{D_{N-1}} \right).
$$

**Now we finally get to the problem**

If I try to solve for a system with constant diffusivity, $D(x) = D_0$, or where $D(x)$ doesn't have too steep gradients, this seems to work fine, but if I use a diffusivity with a larger derivative at the boundary at $x_{N-1}$, it blows up numerically.

So my question is: Is my implementation of the flux boundary condition dubious, and is there a better way to do it? And if so, do anybody have a link or reference to an example of how to implement such a boundary condition?

**Update:**
Actually, it turned out the problem was due to a sign error in my code. But still, if anyone has comments on this implementation of the flux boundary condition, I'd be very interested to hear their thoughts.